# scala/akka: protecting data from race conditions

Tags: scala, akka

I am new to akka. 
Can anyone suggest/confirm that next code/method will be safe in multithreaded environment under heavy load?? 
Question in specifically related to Execute method.
Also will be nice to know general/typical approach for this.
PS. I did try check next article: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html
but this is not Akka specific etc. 
Thanks,

Here is the code:

```
  object ExchangeSystem {

  val openOrders = new ListBuffer[Order]()
  val executedOrders = new ListBuffer[Order]()

  def Execute(matchedOrder: Order, order: Order) : Unit =
  {
     this.synchronized {

        order.SetAsExecuted(order.price)
        matchedOrder.SetAsExecuted(order.price)

        openOrders -= matchedOrder

        executedOrders += order
        executedOrders += matchedOrder
      }
  }


class ExchangeSystem extends Actor {
  import ExchangeSystem._

  def receive = {
    case order : Order => {

      ExchangeSystem.message = order

      // Attempt to match order
      val matchedOrder = ExchangeSystem.matchOrder( order )

      if (matchedOrder != None){
          ExchangeSystem.Execute(matchedOrder.get, order)
      }
      else {
        openOrders += order
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, this is ripe for race conditions due to `ExchangeSystem`'s state being (effectively) global variables.

Rather than having a global object with mutable collections, isolate that state inside an actor (this is one of the chief purposes of actors).

```
class ExchangeSystem extends Actor { 

  var openOrders = List.empty[Order]
  var executedOrders = List.empty[Order]

  def receive = {
    case order : Order => 

      // Attempt to match order
      val matchedOrder = ExchangeSystem.matchOrder( order )

      matchedOrder match {
        case Some(matched) => execute(matched, order)
        case None => openOrders += order
      }

  }

}
```

The `ExchangeSystem.Execute` function should also be moved into the actor, along with the other functions called but not defined in your sample.

You could also move those into an ExchangeSystem class that handles your business logic, composing it inside an actor:

```
case class ExchangeSystem(openOrders: List[Order], executedOrders: List[Order]) {

  def execute(matched: Order, order: Order): ExchangeSystem = {
    order.SetAsExecuted(order.price)
    matchedOrder.SetAsExecuted(order.price)

    this.copy(
      openOrders = openOrders - matchedOrder,
      executedOrders = executedOrders + order + matchedOrder
    )
  }

  def matchOrder(order: Order): Option[Order] = ???
  def withOpenOrder(order: Order): ExchangeSystem = this.copy(openOrders = openOrders + order)
}
```

Note how this object is immutable—it never modifies its own state, instead returning a new `ExchangeSystem` instance with the updated state.  Then you can encapsulate it in an actor like so:

```
class ExchangeSystemActor extends Actor {

  var exchangeSystem = ExchangeSystem(Nil, Nil)

  def receive = {
    case order : Order =>
      // Attempt to match order
      val matchedOrder = exchangeSystem.matchOrder( order )

      matchedOrder match {
        case Some(matched) => exchangeSystem = exchangeSystem.execute(matched, order)
        case None => exchangeSystem = exchangeSystem.withOpenOrder(order)
      }
  }

}
```

Now you've eliminated race conditions, because all operations are taking place through messages passed to the actor.  You've also simplified testing because your business logic can be tested independent of the actor itself—your tests can simply instantiate an `ExchangeSystem` of their own, avoiding the complexity of forcing tests to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify. @Ryan gave good advices regarding reducing the visibility by encapsulating state inside the Actor, but his first statement:

> This is ripe for race conditions due to ExchangeSystem's state being
>   (effectively) global variables.

gives the false impression that race condition *exists*.

Actually, as written, depending on several conditions your code might or might not be safe.

1. If you are accessing only `Execute` method and don't touch `ListBuffer`s directly, then you are **safe**, as this method is synchronized.
2. If you are accessing `Execute` without touching `ListBuffer` fields only from **single** `ExchangeSystem` Actor, you are **perfectly safe** even without explicit synchronization (actually, synchronization is bad practice in this case).

The only case that might violate thread safety here is if you try to modify `ListBuffer` fields directly from different threads/Actors, which is possible, as they are public (but you haven't shown that you do that). That was the @Ryan's point.

Also please note, that when using Actors you should avoid explicit synchronization, please read @Ryan's advice how you can change your code to make it more Actor-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, keeping a data inside an actor was my general feeling. I think second solution will do for me.